# How to check the efficiency of UIMA Annotators?

Tags: information-extraction, uima

I have made a few annotators in UIMA and now, i want to check their efficiency.Is there a standardized way to gauge the performance of the Annotators?

Comment: What kind of performance? Throughput or quality?

Comment: quality of the extracted information.

Answer (score 4):

UIMA itself does not provide immediate support for comparing annotators and evaluating them against a gold standard.

However, there are various tools/implementations out there that provide such functionality on top of UIMA but typically within the confines of the particular tool, e.g.:

- [U-Compare](http://u-compare.org) supports running multiple annotators doing the same thing and comparing their results
- [WebAnno](http://webanno.github.io/webanno/) is an interactive annotation tool that uses UIMA as its backend and that supports comparing annotations from multiple users to each other. There is a class called "CasDiff2" in the code that generates differences and feeds them into [DKPro Statistics](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-statistics/) in the background for the actual agreement calculation. Unfortunately, CasDiff2 cannot be really used separately from WebAnno (yet).

*Disclosure: I'm on the WebAnno team and have implemented CasDiff2 in there.*

Comment: This may help! Thank you!